# Element does not stay fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing an usual issue whereby an element (`resize-icon`) that is `fixed` to the `bottom` `right` ends up "moving" out of position if or when the size of `div input-area` is manipulated using the grey triangle itself (`resize-icon`).

**Is there a hack or even a fix for this?**

Obviously I can write some JS to address this, but I was hoping it would be hackable/fixable with only HTML and or CSS.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Select blue text area.
2. Press enter a bunch of times so that the text area expands.
3. Manually resize the window via grey triangle.
4. Press enter a bunch more times.

[**Here is a codepen.**](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/pdgaPP)

```js
const resizeIcon = document.getElementById('resize-icon'),
      inputArea  = document.getElementById('input-area')
let   cursorX,
      cursorY,
      inputW,
      inputH

resizeIcon.onmousedown = function(e){
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', calculate)
  cursorX = e.clientX
  cursorY = e.clientY
  inputW  = inputArea.offsetWidth
  inputH  = inputArea.offsetHeight
}

const calculate = (e) => {
  xDifference = (e.clientX - cursorX) * 2 // if text box is centered
  yDifference = e.clientY - cursorY
  resize(xDifference, yDifference)
}

const resize = (x, y) => {
  width  = inputW + x + 'px'
  height = inputH + y + 'px'
  inputArea.style.width  = width
  inputArea.style.height = height
}

document.onmouseup = function(){
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', calculate)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#input-area {
  width: 20vw;
  max-width: 90vw;
  min-width: 10vw;
  height: auto; /* was 20vh which caused even more problems */
  min-height: 20vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f2f2f2;

  border:solid red 1px; /**/
}

#user-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border:solid blue 1px; /**/
}

#user-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#resize-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(50%, 50%);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="input-area">
  <div id="user-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div id="resize-icon"></div>
</div>
```

## An explanation as to what is happening:

So, after some more fiddling, I believe I understand what exactly is going on. When you manually resize `input-area` after having already exploited its `height: auto` property (by, say, pressing enter a bunch of times), `user-input` remains larger than `input-area` and this difference persists even though `input-area` and `user-input` will both increase in size in tandem due to their `height: auto` properties. In other words, after manually resizing `input-area` and then exploiting the `height: auto` property of both elements once again, the difference in the actual height between both elements *persists*, and `resize-icon` has become `fixed` in position relative to the new height of `input-area` which was determined manually by the user. **The take-away here is that once you manually resize `input-area` and then exploit the `height: auto` property of it and its child, the difference in height relative to one another persists (i.e. 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6...).**

## A half-baked solution

I would still be interested in knowing any workarounds that are purely HTML and CSS. One solution would be to set `overflow-y: scroll` and `width: calc(100% + sizeOfScrollBar)` for `user-input`, but this is not a good solution since I believe the the width of scrollbars from browser to browser varies.

Comment: Okay, so in CSS I set `#input-area { height : auto }` which fixed this issue in some cases, but I can still manage to break it once I've manually adjusted the size of `#input-area` by using the grey triangle

Comment: can you update the change to your code snippet?

Comment: @YongQuan Sure thing! The codepen is updated btw.

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved without JS. The moment you resize the `input-area`, JS adds `width` and `height` style attribute on it, overriding CSS calculations, while CSS calculation of `resize-icon` rely solely on CSS not inline-style.